# Get Member and navigating through .Net in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I probably do not have an accurate title for this question, but I am just learning powershell and I am pretty confused as of right now.  I have the following situation plus I want to know how to look through .NET functions (at the end of this question) For instance, I have:

```
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
```

I set this to a variable, like so:

```
$test = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
```

If I want to get the methods for this, I do:

```
$test | gm
```

This returns many different Names and membertypes but I only want membertype `method` but if I do:

```
$test | gm -membertype method
```

I do not get any results...however, if I do

```
$test.get_children()
```

it will list the distinguished name and path...**So my question is why, if this is a method, did it now show up when I called `GM -membertype method`??**

Also, if I do

```
,$test.get_children() | gm
```

I get all kinds of different methods but if I do

```
$test.get_children() | gm
```

I receive nothing but `properties`  **Why does it not show the methods?**  I should also note I was unable to use any of the Membertype methods for `,$test.get_childre() | gm`

This doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  Can someone please explain this and how to determine what I can do with specific .NET functions.  Another such example would be :

```
$domain = [System.DirecotryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]
```

**How can I navigate through this?  So I'd imagine I should do System. -> and see what is available and pick DirectoryServices -> and see what is avialable from there**

Comment: [system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain] | gm

Comment: And I guess the other thing you are seeing is due to the adapter ([adsi]) powershell has for that class. If you do $test.psbase | gm you will see the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to list the methods using the following approach:

```
$test = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry    
$test.psbase | get-member -force -Type Method
```

Without specifying the -Force parameter, you will not be able to see all of the methods that you are looking for on that object.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the methods and all other hidden members using this method:

```
$test | gm -MemberType method -View All -Force
```

Type this at your console for more information:

```
 help gm -param view
```